# How to print the next week using the date command?

Tags: linux, date

How to print the next week using the date command ?

```
date +"This is week: %U of %Y, Sprint: %y(W%U-%U)"
```

The output should be

```
This is week: 04 of 2017, Sprint: 17(W04-05)
```

Instead of

```
This is week: 04 of 2017, Sprint: 17(W04-04)
```

Comment: If the existing answer solves your problem, please consider accepting it via the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

With GNU `date`:

```
date +"This is week: %U of %Y, Sprint: %y(W%U-$(date -d 'now + 7 days' +%U))"
```

alternatively:

```
date +"This is week: %U of %Y, Sprint: %y(W%U-$(date -d 'next week 12:00' +%U))"
```

Comment: Would be better as `date -d 'next week 12:00'` in timezones that have DST. For instance, in mainland UK, `faketime '2017-03-19 23:30' date +%W-%F-%R` outputs `11-2017-03-19-23:30` and `faketime '2017-03-19 23:30' date -d 'next week' +%W-%F-%R` outputs `13-2017-03-27-00:30`

Comment: I'm all for improvement! so amended

Comment: I wonder how much time DST saves. I don't know if it is big or small, but I do know the sign (-).